# Testing the effect of spatial differences

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, t-test

I have a closed room. I release some bacteria in the middle of it and let it settle onto previously located plates on the floor. Once the bacteria settles I collect the plates and count up how many bacteria are on each.  I then have an idea of a spatial distribution. Results might look something like the contour plot:

[image]

**Question:**

So here's the question. How can I "test" (rigorously) whether distance from the source is an important factor in the distribution of results?

Comment: When I hear "contour plot" I think of lines of constant value as in the following: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/contour-plots.html

Comment: The plates are grouped in the center of each rectangle. And coloured based on concentration of bacteria. If we didn't have a contour or mapping plot of any type what would a statistical test be to see if distance from the injection point was important in influencing the results?